# Replace sub-string except if within predefined multi-characters delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Input string is as follows:

```
I am Checking Images whose id is being shown in chapters view as 
*img*id:14*img* and some other stuff; I want to replace "id" to 
"identification" except for the instance that appears within the 
*img* delimiters.
```

The expected result is:

```
I am Checking Images whose identification is being shown in chapters 
view as *img*id:14*img* and some other stuff; I want to replace 
"identification" to "identificastionentification" except for the 
instance that appears within the *img* delimiters.
```

Code I have tried:

```
$scope.This_Page.Dislayed_HTML = $scope.This_Page.Dislayed_HTML.replace('/[^[*]img[*]{"id":([0-9]*)}[*]img[*] ' + $scope.This_Page.Search_String +']/+ig'                            ,
                                                                                '<span style="background-color: rgb(52, 235, 149,0.3);border:dotted 2px green">' + $scope.This_Page.Search_String + '</span>' ) ;
```

While

`$scope.This_Page.Dislayed_HTML` include my html code.

`$scope.This_Page.Search_String` is string that I want to search in my html.

`[*]img[*]{"id":([0-9]*)}[*]img[*]` is the delimeter that I want to ignore in my search.

Meaning, that if `$scope.This_Page.Search_String` = 'img' it won't find the img that in the delimeter.

Comment: on what rules you're changing input string to output string ? any code you have tried so far ? post that too if you have tried anything

Comment: @CodeManiac, I'm not sure I understand your question. I need (in javascript) to replace all instances of a certain set of characters found within the text to a different set of characters, except if the found match is within two ***img*** tags. In the example above, the idea is to replace **id** to **identification** (that also created the funny **identificastionentification**).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that maybe you are trying to do:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0eYaPE/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?!\*img\*id:([0-9]*)\*img\*)"id"/gm;
const str = `I am Checking Images whose id is being shown in chapters view as 
*img*id:14*img* and some other stuff; I want to replace "id" to 
"identification" except for the instance that appears within the 
*img* delimiters.
The expected result is:

I am Checking Images whose identification is being shown in chapters 
view as *img*id:14*img* and some other stuff; I want to replace 
"identification" to "identificastionentification" except for the 
instance that appears within the *img* delimiters.`;
const subst = `"identification"`;


const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BhXBzY/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/BhXBzY/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I can't understand how that can help me. I want to search in the string the keyword "img" but I don't want in will find the img that in the regex. I simple want to replace any accurance of the "Search_String" to be with some style that mark this keyword in the html string.